# CSS and Javascript assets are not reflecting changes on refresh

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

To keep it simple I'm placing...

- My CSS styles in *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*
- My javascripts in app/javascript/custom/index.js

To load that javascript I just add *<%= javascript_include_tag "custom/index" %&gt*; to *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*

At the end of *rails assets:precompile* I have, among other things, this code that the server send to the browser...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-ed7f657c82113ab3654e0f1c0a9fb78eb9439717ba426d64a05914a481e366bf.css" data-turbo-track="reload" />
.
.
.
<script src="/assets/custom/index-a244844108f7509a3d2f83eb57ee786e886c7ebee146c23c1713958fe7d46120.js"></script>
```

But my real code looks diferent, of course.

So, to see the result of some change into my CSS styles or my javascript code, I have to wait until *precompile*, reload the page and sometimes event restart the server.

I'm pretty sure that this is not the proper way to work. What would be that proper way?
What is the way to write CSS and javascript and prove it easily with Rails 7? What about the images?

Comment: run `bin/rails assets:clobber` and stop precompiling

Comment: @Alex, stop precompiling means don't run rails assets:precompile anymore in dev? Just that !!!. I love rails. Imagine when I really learn it.

Comment: yes, precompile command is meant for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not precompile in development, run this to remove precompiled assets:

```bash
bin/rails assets:clobber
```

When you precompile, all your assets are processed and are placed in `public/assets` directory, these assets do not change automatically and take priority.

When you don't have a corresponding asset in `public/assets`, `sprockets` will locate updated assets in your assets paths (`Rails.application.config.assets.paths`), it will run any processing that sprockets knows how to do (like minification or compiling `.erb` assets), and it will serve new and updated assets on the fly when you refresh the page.

This whole process is very slow, this is why in production we do `bin/rails assets:precompile` to preprocess assets only once ahead of time.